# I am creating customer slider with following codes but its not working Need Solutions

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I am trying to create a slider which will fetch all slider data from data base. Following are my codes. The output is showing very awkward. I am also attaching slider screen shot.  I have tried alot but unable to figure-out what am i doing wrong?

**Slider Output Link**

[image: slider output image]

**Header Section**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Swiper demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
```

**Style**

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

**Body**

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<!-- Start Our Recommendations -->
<section>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; background-color: #8F7224;">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;" class="p-3 text-white font-weight-bold">
                Our
                <span>
                    Recommendations
                </span>
            </h1>
            <?php

                global $wpdb;
                $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `argent`");

                echo "<div>";
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    echo "<div class=\"swiper-container-initialized-per-four\">";
                    echo "<div class=\"swiper-wrapper\">";
                    echo "<div class=\"swiper-slide\">";
                    echo    "<h1>". $row->id ."</h1>";
                    echo    "<img style=\"height: 250px; width: 250px; object-fit: fill;\" src=\" $row->drama_thumbnail \" ?>";
                    echo "</div>"; 
                } 
                echo "</div>"; 
                echo "<div class=\"swiper-button-next\"></div>"; 
                echo "<div class=\"swiper-button-prev\"></div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Scripts**

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-initialized-per-four', {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 40,
        freeMode: true,
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    });
</script>
```

**SQL Table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `argent` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `drama_thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-indenting your code it looks obvious you are opening 2 `<div>` inside the `foreach` loop, but you are closing them outside the loop. I think you want to create them only once, so try putting them outside the loop:

```php
echo "<div>";
echo "<div class=\"swiper-container-initialized-per-four\">";
echo "<div class=\"swiper-wrapper\">";

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<div class=\"swiper-slide\">";
    echo    "<h1>". $row->id ."</h1>";
    echo    "<img style=\"height: 250px; width: 250px; object-fit: fill;\" src=\" $row->drama_thumbnail \" ?>";
    echo "</div>"; 
} 
                
echo "</div>"; 
echo "<div class=\"swiper-button-next\"></div>"; 
echo "<div class=\"swiper-button-prev\"></div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```